# Is "they" singular or plural in this context?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, pronouns

Hypothetically, in the context of

> -What's your favorite restaurant to eat food
>
> -If they have food, I'll eat it" was said.

Would "they" be singular or plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Some who dislike the singular *they* might argue that in your sentence, *they* refers to the people who operate the restaurant. But in practice, *they* means the restaurant as an indivisible entity, not the collection of people who own, manage, and staff it.

Comment: So would it be singular?

Comment: Oh, sorry :-) I read your original question as , "Is *they* singular?" rather than "singular or plural." Though the answer is fuzzy, I'd rule it as singular because its antecedent is the **singular** noun "restaurant."

Comment: Thank you Paul Tanenbaum

Comment: *They* is the third person plural pronoun. It's plural by definition, and as you can see, it takes the third person plural verb form *have*. That's a grammatical notion. As a semantic matter, we can ask whether the pronoun's antecedent is singular or plural, i.e., does the pronoun refer to one person (in this case) or more than one. Ordinarily, pronouns and their antecedents agree in number, but that's not always the case. Since English doesn't have a good way to refer to noun of indeterminate gender -- "someone ... he"? or "someone ... she"? certainly not "someone ... it" -- we use *they*.

Comment: Also, some transgendered people prefer the pronoun *they* to refer to themselves individually.

Comment: I would add to the remarks of @user105719 that *they* in 2020 is in much the same position as *you* was a few centuries ago. It was only plural (the singular was *thou*), but now is used as both plural and singular... always with the plural form of the verb. Singular *they* is headed toward a future of complete respectability.